# jQuery event handler does not work in this code

Tags: jquery, events, click

I am currently unable to get this code to work using jQuery. The same event works when I add it specifically on the "a" link element. I would expect jQuery to register an alert to be shown when the link is clicked but nothing happens when I click on that link. I am running this html in Chrome and DevTools console does not show any errors at all! I am not sure what I could be doing wrong as I am doing it just by the book! Overall I have seen jQuery is not working for anything javascript but I have posted this small piece of code to illustrate. Appreciate any help figuring out what I could be doing wrong!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- jQuery version 3.3.1 -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" />
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function() {
        //This should show an alert when any link on the page is clicked.
        alert("This is a test");
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#">Click here to see alert</a>
  <!-- This does not work! -->
  <!-- This works fine!
                <a href="#" onclick="javascript:alert('This is a test');">Click here to see alert</a> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because a `script` tag is not self-closing. You need to add a separate `</script>` tag after your jQuery.js reference:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function() {
        console.log("This is a test");
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#">Click here to see alert</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason your `onclick="javascript:alert('This is a test');"` still works is because it doesn't rely on the broken reference to jQuery.

That said, you should avoid using `on*` event attributes as they are very outdated. Unobtrusive event handlers are by far the best practice here.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you so much for the quick reply! :)

Comment: I cannot visibly upvote the answer but I have upvoted. thanks again!